# De-Normalizing Table Data - Excel functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have an Excel time-sheet table/matrix which needs to be 'de-normalized' in order to prepare data to use in a pivot table.

My table contains time-sheet entries with each cell representing a 15 minute slot dedicated to a particular task (Rows = time-slots) (Columns = Dates).

EXAMPLE:

CURRENT DATA

```
    A           B           C           D           E           ..      ..
    ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------  ----------  -----------
1|              01-Jan-14   02-Jan-14   03-Jan-14   04-Jan-14   ..      ..
2|   00:00      task1       task3       task3       task1       ..      ..
3|   00:15      task1       task3       task2       task1       ..      ..
4|   00:30      task2       task3       task2       task1       ..      ..
5|   01:45      task3       task3       task3       task2       ..      ..
    ..
    ..
```

DESIRED RESULT (IN NEW SHEET):

```
    A           B           C
  ------------  ----------- ------  
1|   Date       Task        Count  
2|   01-Jan-14  task1       2 
3|   01-Jan-14  task2       1
4|   01-Jan-14  task3       1
5|   02-Jan-14  task3       4 
6|   03-Jan-14  task3       2
7|   03-Jan-14  task2       2
8|   03-Jan-14  task1       3
9|   04-Jan-14  task2       1
..
..
```

Please note that i have a fixed number of rows (time slots) and variable number of columns (although I have 1 column for each day of the year - Leap years result in fewer days/columns in some years)

I want to avoid VBA if at all possible however, however these solutions would not be ignored if they can solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without VBA I can proffer the following solution:

In your desired result

```
A2 =INDEX(CurrentData!$1:$1,,(ROW(A1)-1)/4+2)
B2 =INDEX(CurrentData!$2:$5,MOD(ROW(A1)-1;4)+1,(ROW(A1)-1)/4+2)
```

The 4 in these formulas has to be changed to your row count. As well the $5 to your row count +1.

This should be usable in a pivot table. Counting is pivot tables task.

Greetings

Axel

Comment: Edit: should use default English list separators

Comment: Thanks a lot - a little tweaking to get it to work with my actual sheet and row counts and starting positions were different to example. But your explanation helped.
Thank you